# Error when I try to git push heroku in a git bash here

Tags: git, heroku

I made a discord bot using node.js. I am trying to host this bot on `Heroku`. I opened a `git bash here` in my bot's folder. I have already done `git add .`, added a `Procfile`, `.gitignore` file.
If you could help it would be greatly appreciated.

`git commit -m "First commit"`. After that, I tried to do `git push heroku`. I got this error.

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream heroku master
'
```

After I did `git push --set-upstream heroku master` I got another error saying,

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/japan-service-helper.git'
```

I want it to upload to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can push your code to Heroku you need to

1. sign up for Heroku,
2. create an app on Heroku, either via the web interface or [by running](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/creating-apps)

   ```
   heroku create <optional-app-name>
   ```
3. connect your code to your Heroku app by [adding a remote](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#creating-a-heroku-remote). `heroku create` would normally do this for you, but it looks like you don't have a `heroku` remote yet. You can add one by running

   ```
   heroku git:remote -a <name-of-existing-heroku-app-to-use>
   ```

Once that's done you should have a remote called `heroku`. Verify by running `git remote -v`, then proceed with `git push heroku` from your `master` branch.